# "Too many attempts. Please try later." message on first Dropbox login after install

Tags: dropbox

Fresh Android 5.1 phone, just installed Dropbox app from Android Play Store. Started the app, tried to log in for the first time, got a message: *"Too many attempts. Please try later"*

Dropbox works OK on my other devices, including my previous Android phone.

I did some googling, and it seems that other people did face the same problem recently:

[Dropbox Community Forum thread](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205115723--Too-many-attempts-Please-try-later-won-t-go-away), a comments suggest that retrying after several hours may solve the problem. This workaround didn't help in my case (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the current version of the app is buggy.  Nothing we can do about that.

However, [a workaround was posted](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205463163-Too-many-login-attempts-Try-again-later-):

> I navigated into the website login > account > security > two-step verification. Added my phone number as my 2nd step of verification (they send a code for new logins) and low and behold I got into the app first try with no problems!

Using an older version of DropBox might also work.  I'd suggest [5.2.6](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/dropbox-inc/dropbox/dropbox-5-2-6-release/dropbox-5-2-6-2-android-apk-download/), from February before the issue appeared.

Comment: I enabled 2-step verification (using Google Authenticator instead SMS messages), and it actually fixed the problem.